# Divergence for $p$ prime numbers and convergence for $m$ composite numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Does there exist a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} \in \mathbb C^{\mathbb N}$ such that  :

> For all $p$ prime numbers the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a_n^p$ diverges,
>   and for all composite $m>0$ the serie  $\displaystyle  \sum_{n\in \mathbb N} a_n^m$ converges ?

My guess :

I know there exist a serie $\displaystyle\sum \frac{\cos(\frac{2}{3}\pi n)}{\ln(1+n)}$ converge but
$$
\displaystyle\sum \left(\frac{\cos(\frac{2}{3}\pi n)}{\ln (1+n)}\right)^3
$$
diverges so I think that the answer is yes.

And I have seen that there exist a convergent serie $\displaystyle\sum  a_n$ such that
$$
\displaystyle\sum a_n^\alpha, \quad \alpha\in \mathbb{N}, \alpha>1
$$
diverges.

*Proof.*

For exemple
$$
a_{3k}=\frac{2}{\ln(k)}, \quad a_{3k-1}=a_{3k+1}=-\frac{1}{\ln(k)}(k=2,3,\cdots).
$$

Comment: Aren't prime numbers integers?  How can something diverge for all primes and converge for all integers?  There's something wrong with how you're posing this problem.

Comment: The editing did not fix the problem. Do you mean that for all **composite** $m$ we have convergence?

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, I was not focused,now it's ok.

Comment: I believe this is from IMC.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm sorry to interrupt you, do you have any ideas to prove the following statement ?

Comment: I have no ideas towards a solution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is problem 5 from day 1 of the 2013 IMC. See [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=79&t=547818) for one solution, and [the official solution](http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2013/IMC2013-day1-solutions.pdf).

Comment: The first one is interesting, do you have a reference for the lemma ?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've heard from a friend that this problem was actually given as homework for a class at cambridge (?), but obviously not many people got it.

Answer (score 4):

For real sequences, this is impossible.  If the series converges for any even exponent $m$, then $a_n\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, and hence $|a_n|^{m'} < |a_n|^{m}$ for sufficiently large $n$ and any $m'>m$.  Therefore, if the series converges for *any* even exponent, it is absolutely convergent for *all* larger exponents.  (In particular, if it converges for $m=4$, then it must converge for all primes $p\ge 5$.)

Comment: On the other hand, there are real sequences $a_n$ such that $\sum a_n^p$ diverges for all primes $p$, and $\sum a_n^m$ converges for all *odd* composite numbers $m$. As you point out, any such sequence must also diverge for all even $m$.

Comment: We works with complexe sequences here..

Answer (score 2):

That can't exist for positive $a_n$ at least. Take primes $p$ and $q$, and a composite $m$ such that $p < m < q$. Then if $\sum a_n^q$ converges, by the comparison test $\sum a_n^m$ converges too. It looks to me that this should work for all $a_n$, but I don't see how to prove it offhand.

Comment: It's interesting (+1). Thanks